# is using alias on aggregate column is different to not using?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, column-alias

Are following two SQLs equivalent, regarding performance? Which one is better?

```sql
SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS c
FROM student
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY c DESC
;
```

```sql
SELECT name, COUNT(name)
FROM student
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC
;
```

Comment: I'd go with column alias. Less to type, thus less risk of inconsistencies.

Comment: Check the execution plan.